# Solve $y''' - (a+2)y''+(2a+1)y'-ay = 1$

Tags: calculus

**Question:**

Solve

$$y''' - (a+2)y''+(2a+1)y'-ay = 1$$

No restrictions are placed on $a$, but we can assume that $a \in \mathbb{R}$. The expected answer divides answers based on being $a = 1$, $a = 0$ and $a \neq 1$ or $0$.

**Attempted solution:**

Since this contains an unknown constant $a$, I assume that there will be different solutions depending on the value of a. In particular, sometimes the coefficients before could be zero, for instance.

The characteristic polynomial becomes:

$$p(r) = r^3 -(a+2)r^2 + (2a+1)r -a = (r-a)(r-1)^2$$

The solutions to the characteristic polynomial thus becomes:

$$r_1 = a$$
$$r_2 = r_3 = 1$$

The solution to the homogeneous equation becomes:

$$y_h = C_1e^{ax} + (C_2 + C_3x)e^{x}$$

The particular solution $y_p(x)$ probably has the form:

$$y_p(x) = b$$

Taking the trivial derivative as many time as we need:

$$y'_p(x) = y''_p(x) = y'''_p(x) = 0$$

Putting this back into the original equation removes all terms but the last one on the left-hand side gives:

$$-ab = 1 \Rightarrow b = -\frac{1}{a}$$

Thus, the particular solution becomes:

$$y_p(x) = -\frac{1}{a}$$

The total solution finally becomes:

$$y(x) = y_h + y_p = C_1e^{ax} + (C_2 + C_3x)e^{x} - \frac{1}{a}$$

However, the expected solution is:

$$(Ax+B)e^x + Ce^{ax} - \frac{1}{a},~~~~~~a \neq 0, a \neq 1$$
$$(Ax^2+Bx+C)e^x - 1, ~~~~~~a = 1$$
$$(Ax + B)e^x + C + x, ~~~~~~a = 0$$

So I got the solution for $a \neq 0, a \neq 1$ without too much effort.

I can understand how they get the $a = 1$ solution, because it is a triple root for the characteristic polynomial and $-1/1 = -1$ for the particular solution.

However, I am stuck on how to get the solution for $a = 0$. I tried just putting $a = 0$ in the original equation, which then becomes:

$$y''' - 2y'' -y' = 1$$

This ends up becoming (here I just used Wolfram Alpha to explore different ways to get the case for $a = 0$ before doing it on paper independently):

$$y(x) = c_1 +c_2e^{(1-\sqrt{2})x} + c_3e^{(1+\sqrt{2})x} - x$$

...while the expected answer for $a = 0$ is:

$$(Ax+B)e^x + C + x$$

I can get a glimpse of how it works by noting that $e^{0x} = e^0 = 1$ and therefore one of the constants should be alone, but that is all I got.

How to finish this question off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing complicated happend; you just solved the wrong equation. For $a=0$ it should be
$$y'''-2y''\color{red}+y'=1$$
And, indeed, the solution for this equation coincides with the given one.